# JK flip-flop in Logisim

Tags: flipflop, logisim

I'm trying to create a JK flip-flop using Logisim, but I don't get an output.

[image: JK flipflop in Logisim]

Can somebody help me find the problem?

Comment: if you want to simulate JK flip flop operation you can use this website https://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-jkff.html

Comment: Use microcap v12. Search spectrum-soft.com

Comment: https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110 here is the link.

Answer (score 1):

> Can somebody help me find the problem

Logisim does not model gate delays.

Logisim is not appropriate for this kind of simulation which requires gate delays to provide the expected results. For some circuits you may get what you expected, out of luck, due to the order the software evaluate the logic level changes.

Answer (score 0):

> do u know any website or app that can model gate delays?

There is an online circuit emulator at falstad.com. It comes in two varieties:

- [JavaScript](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/)
- [Java](https://www.falstad.com/circuit-java/)

Both have a number of [circuit examples](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-index.html), including a [JK flipflop](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-jkff.html):

[image: Screenshot of JK flipflop on falstad.com]

---

If you need an application to run locally, you could use [MicroCap 12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm), which is free and SPICE based, but it is for Windows only.

For OS X, there is [MacSpice](http://www.macspice.com/), which is the application that I use and is really rather good.