# Why doesn't my JK FlipFlop built in Logisim work?

Tags: circuit-design

My JK Flip Flop in Logisim doesn't work and it shows the oscillation apparent error and I can't figure out why. I do remember seeing a similar question where one of the answers claimed that a circuit like this simply can't be built in Logisim because of the way I/O and signals are simulated, that circuit was a JK Flip Flop build with NAND gates.

[JK flip-flop in Logisim](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/648983/jk-flip-flop-in-logisim)

Also I see video of JK Flip Flops built in Logisim that make use of the built in D latch circuit under the memory components instead of only using the basic logic gates of AND/NOR- NAND for the different types of JK flip flops as I and the person who asked the question above were trying to do.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-vUvqgpMZ4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWRU6_MbDT0&t=1s

If it's not possible to simulate such a circuit using the drag and drop features in Logisim, I wonder if it would be possible to create such functionally using the JAR archive feature and coding a JK flip flop library in Java.

[image: JK Flip Flop using NOR gates]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: your JK FF circuit is missing a stage

Comment: Your circuit is not correct. This is not how JK FF should be built. You have a race condition in this circuit. If all inputs of the AND gate are logic 1. The AND gate output will also be at the HIGH state.  But this means that NOR gate output must be at a LOW state.  And this "0" will be "fed back" (positive feedback) to AND gate input causing the AND gate output go to a low state. This again forces the HIGH state at the NOR gate output which forces HIGH at the AND gate output. This process results in an oscillation between the HIGH and LOW states.   https://tinyurl.com/yowzofvh

Comment: @jsotola Please point out what's missing , I copied the JK flip flop from this link here , probably should have mentioned that in the original post  , the JK flip flop I've done in Logisim is copied from that link below   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/digital_circuits/digital_circuits_flip_flops.htm

Comment: @G36 I see some difference in the JK flip flop you've done vs the one i've done , mine had the signals from the NOR gates output feeding back into the 3rd inputs of the AND gates starting at the same place where the output signal of one NOR gate feeds into the input of the other. So Ichanged my circuit to be JUST LIKE YOUR   with the output of the NOR gates looping back into the AND gates inputs starting  AFTER the output of  one NOR gate goes into the 2nd input of the other. The circuit still has the oscillation aapprent error when both inputs are 1 though

Comment: @G36 I'm guessing that's the way the circuit should work because two 1 inputs for the SR latch after  the AND gates is an undefined state or race condition but it just seems strange that logisim won't simulate the circuit with the 3 inputs of the AND gates connected  from the beginning , I have to disconnect the 2 inputs that loop back from the NOR gate outputs then turn the clock signal & the J&/orK inputs on/off  to get an  output at Q or Q' of the NOR gate outputs then connect that back to the 3rd input of the AND gates with everything working as it should for  0/1 or 1/0 inputs before the

Comment: @G36 oscillation apparent error occurs with a 1/1 input, Maybe my problem is that I expect too much from the logisim software , idk

Comment: @6502Assembly4NESgames my apologies ... I had the `master-slave JK FF` in my head and I thought that you were talking about that